# Random numbers are the same after every loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, random

My program is supposed to display a pair of dice for every roll, which works as planned. I'd like it to repeat multiple times but every time it repeats it's no longer random and just repeats the assigned number from line 2 and 3. If I roll a 2 and a 3, it repeats a 2 and 3 every time. 
How can I make it so that a new random number is assigned each time it loops?

```
import random
dice1 = random.randrange(1,6)
dice2 = random.randrange(1,6)
```

... [Edit:]

```
visualdice_1 =( """
            +-------+
            |       |
            |   *   |
            |       |
            +-------+""")

visualdice_2 =( """
            +-------+
            | *     |
            |       |
            |     * |
            +-------+""")
```

then associates with

```
def showdice():
#Dice1 Visual Execution
    if dice1 == 1:
        print(visualdice_1)
    if dice1 == 2:
        print(visualdice_2)

def start():
    confirmation = input("Would you like to roll the dice? (Y/N): ")
    if confirmation == "Y" or confirmation == "y":
        print ("You've rolled:",dice1,"and", dice2), showdice()
        return start()
    else:
        print("Goodbye")
start()
```

Comment: Don't use recursion to implement a simple loop.  You're just wasting stack space.

Comment: Also, that `print(…), showdice(…)` is at best misleading code. If you meant two separate statements, put them on separate lines (or, if you must, use a semicolon). What you're doing here is creating a tuple of two `None` values in a very complicated way, and then ignoring that tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've found your own problem in your description: *"the assigned number from line 2 and 3"*. You assign the number above your loop.

instead, put the random number generator inside the loop, and edit your `showdice()` function to take as an argument your dice value:

```
def showdice(dice):
#Dice1 Visual Execution
    if dice == 1:
        print(visualdice_1)
    if dice == 2:
        print(visualdice_2)
    # I suppose this continues until "if dice == 6"...
    ...

def start():
    dice1 = random.randrange(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randrange(1,6)
    confirmation = input("Would you like to roll the dice? (Y/N): ")
    if confirmation == "Y" or confirmation == "y":
        print ("You've rolled:",dice1,"and", dice2)
        showdice(dice1)
        showdice(dice2)
        return start()
    else:
        print("Goodbye")
start()
```

Otherwise, it will always use the same randomly rolled dice that you instantiated at the top of your script.

Comment: I tried this, but the cut out showdice() function no longer works because it no longer recognizes dice1 and dice2 variables. Can I merge the two functions somehow?

Comment: if dice1 == 1:
        print(visualdice_1)
    if dice1 == 2:
        print(visualdice_2)
etc... 
visualdice_1 is a graphic of a dice 
visualdice_1 =( """
            +-------+
            |       |
            |   *   |
            |       |
            +-------+""") 
like so

Comment: @jeaneroo What you probably want to do is pass the die rolls to showdice, like `showdice(dice1, dice2)`. And of course you also have to change to `def showdice` line to take those parameters, and maybe change the body to use those parameters instead of the globals.

Comment: Could you post your full definition of `showdice()` as an edit to your question?

Comment: I edited my post @sacul, the showdice is supposed associate the "image" of the result, for example 1, with visualdice1 for the first dice

Comment: See my edits, I think that should take care of it. Note that, as chepner said in their comment, recursion is a bit much here, but I left it as is. There are definitely other ways to write this little game.

Comment: @jeaneroo note also that `random.randrange(1,6)` will never output 6 (it is not inclusive of the stop argument). You probably want `random.randrange(1,7)` (unless you have a 5 sided dice)

Comment: Excellent, it works perfectly. I understand this code is probably comparable to garbage, but I'm an absolute beginner. Cheers, can't thank you enough.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! It's not garbage, there are just other, perhaps more efficient, ways to do things ;) Good luck with future coding ventures, and please accept answers that solve your problem (it helps the answerers get reputation points, and you get a little bit of reputation from it too)!

Answer (score 0):

Just rerun:

```
dice1 = random.randrange(1,6)
dice2 = random.randrange(1,6)
```

Before the print function.